# Exchange Managed API determine if email has been anwered - PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

Is there a way to determine if a given email in the inbox has been answered (Reply to Sender)

Actually I am using the following code, which does not work correct

```
ExtendedPropertyDefinition pr_last_verb_executed = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x1081, MapiPropertyType.Integer);
PropertySet psPropSet = new PropertySet(pr_last_verb_executed);

ItemId itemId = new ItemId("<PLACEHOLDER FOR AN Exchange EMail ID>");
EmailMessage serverMail = EmailMessage.Bind(exchangeService, itemId, psPropSet);

int lastState = 0; // should become 102 if email has been answered
serverMail.TryGetProperty(pr_last_verb_executed, out lastState);  // does not return anything to variable lastState
```

Comment: Have you turned on logging? EWS usually give at least workable warnings.

Comment: Has the message in question actually been replied to? What is the return value of your call to `TryGetProperty`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I found out updating Exchange Server to a newer version solves this problem. So this ia a bug in older versions of Microsoft Exchange Server.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do would be to look at the messages in question with a MAPI editor like MFCMapi or OutlookSpy that will tell you if that property has been set or not (its an optional property set by the client). The property is just an indicator of the last action a client took https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee218425(v=exchg.80).aspx reply is one action but there are many others. PidTagIconIndex https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc815472.aspx is another indicator property you can use to do the same thing. EWS also have conversation operations https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn610351(v=exchg.150).aspx if you are looking to work with conversation.

Cheers
Glen